# Getting specific data from JSON array. [PHP]

Tags: php, json

I have a script that pulls data from an external API. The output example is below.

```
[{"id": "579144bbfbd8f54f53f5394b", "username": "test1", "type": "1", "email": "new_user@email.com", "status": on},{"id": "afadfatqwertqr", "username": "test2", "type": "1", "email": "new_user2@email.com", "status": on}]
```

I am trying to pull the id solely from the string to set it as a variable. It has to be username specific as well but any support would be greatly appreciated. Been racking my head, thanks in advance!

Comment: don't use regex, if its a json string, use `json_decode`. use the proper tool, not regex

Comment: Suggest using `json_decode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$usernameToFind = 'something';
```

Then you need to call your api get JSONResponse;

```
$arr = json_decode($yourJSON, true);
```

then your `$arr` will contain all data as array of object. and you can access as below:

```
$username = array();

$len = count($arr);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
    $id = $arr[$i]["id"];
    $uname = $arr[$i]["username"];
    $username[$uname] = $id;
}
```

After this loop you can get whatever id you want to find based on username given that `usernameToFind` exist in that array. To check that you can use:

```
if(isset($username[$usernameToFind])){
    $idToFind = $username[$usernameToFind];
}else{
    echo "this user doesn't exist";
}
```

Comment: This worked, how would I go about getting from the ID based on the username value? Thanks alot.

Comment: @JayC You don't need that actually as they are in same index of an array. You can think of property of same object. So when you are accessing id of index 0 you are actually accessing id of the username of object which is in index 0. maybe I didn't understand your question quite well.

Comment: I am trying to pull the ID from specific username. All the IDs are unique and so are the usernames (did not have it this way in original post by accident. Have now updated it.) Thanks again @AsifRahaman

Comment: @JayC Check my edited answer and let me know if that works for you :)

Comment: @AsifRahaman I am getting no response at all, even with error_reporting(E_ALL). Just a blank page. $username will be defined before this script, and will be used to get the ID of that user. If that helps.

Comment: @JayC do you want to get username specific id from external API or get it from API response shown in the question?

Comment: @JayC then you can use the method shown in my edited answer. ohh... I get it now...you've all the username and id from api but you want to get a specific id based on a username...right??

Comment: Worked seamlessly! Thanks a ton.